# Get value from xml tags with using string function

Tags: objective-c, xml, string

hello this is my xml in one string...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 

xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<soap:Body><CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse 

xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>73.4</CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>

</CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

i want 73.4 from this `<CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>73.4</CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>` ...is ther any quickest method using string functions for doing this? ...don't want to traverse whole xml!

Comment: If the data is XML then you really _should_ use an XML parser, for example [SXMLDocument](http://nfarina.com/post/2843708636/a-lightweight-xml-parser-for-ios).  There are many many ways to represent the same XML infoset, with namespace prefixes (`<ns1:CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">`), whitespace inside tags (`<CelsiusToFahrenheitResult  >73.4</CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>`) etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple solution without using an xml-parser would be to use `NSRegularExpression`. Something like this:

```
NSString *pattern = @"<CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>(.*)</CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:nil];
__block NSString *fahrenheitString = nil;
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:yourString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [yourString length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){
    if (0 < [match numberOfRanges]) {
        NSRange range = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
        fahrenheitString = [yourString substringWithRange:range];
    }    
}];
```

Comment: awesome!! ...by this i got <CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>73.4</CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>
..now how to extract 73.4 from this?

Comment: updated answer to reflect matching correct index. the first match always contains the entire pattern.

Comment: hey ...is it safe to regular expresion for extracting value from xml tag of response of web service, can it fail any how? or i should go fo xml parsing for that?

Comment: Using regular expressions is more fragile than using an XML parser. However, it will fail gracefully and the string will be nil when it doesn't succeed to match the tags.